Cannot run "Hello Android XR" app in XR Emulator
I've recently installed Android Studio Meerkat | 2024.3.1 Canary 7 (for macOS Sequoia), then downloaded and configured a Virtual XR Device for emulation process. The XR Emulator works fine, as expected. Google has posted a Kotlin sample project called Hello Android XR on the GitHub. When running the project on the XR Emulator, the following error occurs:
Error loading build artifacts from: /Users/swift/Desktop/
android-xr/app/build/intermediates/apk_ide_redirect_file/debug/
createDebugApkListingFileRedirect/redirect.txt

Question – How to fix this error?

